# Using facebook-php-sdk-v4 to do a resumable upload of video to facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the SDK found here:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4

In addition, I'm using the process found here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads

Here is a summary of the relevant code I have so far:

```
                $path = '/' . $fb->getUid() . '/videos';
            $params = array('upload_phase' => 'start', 'file_size' => filesize($fileName));
            $startResult = (new \Facebook\FacebookRequest($this->fbSession, 'POST', $path, $params, 'v2.3'))->execute()->getGraphObject();
print_r($startResult);
            $startOffset = $startResult->getProperty('start_offset');
            $endOffset = $chunkSize = $startResult->getProperty('end_offset');
            $uploadSessionId = $startResult->getProperty('upload_session_id');
            chdir(sys_get_temp_dir());
            $splitCmd = "split --bytes=$chunkSize --suffix-length=1 --numeric-suffixes $fileName {$prefix}";
            exec($splitCmd);
            $part = 0;
            while(($startOffset < $endOffset) && ($part <= 10))
            {
                $curChunk = sys_get_temp_dir() . '/' . $prefix . $part;
                $params = array('upload_phase' => 'transfer',
                    'start_offset' => $startOffset,
                    'upload_session_id' => $uploadSessionId,
                    'video_file_chunk' => '@' . $curChunk);
print_r($params);echo "\n";
                $upldResult = (new \Facebook\FacebookRequest($this->fbSession, 'POST', $path, $params, 'v2.3'))->execute()->getGraphObject();
                $startOffset = $upldResult->getProperty('start_offset');
                $endOffset = $upldResult->getProperty('end_offset');
                unlink($curChunk);
                $part++;
echo "$startOffset > $endOffset\n";
            }
echo "Done uploading\n";
            $params = array('upload_session_id' => $uploadSessionId,
                'upload_phase' => 'finish',
                'title' => 'My Title',
                'description' => 'My Description',
                );
print_r($params); echo "\n";
            $postResult = (new \Facebook\FacebookRequest($this->fbSession, 'POST', $path, $params, 'v2.3'))->execute()->getGraphObject();
print_r($postResult);
```

There is an exception thrown everytime on the $upldResult line:
                    $upldResult = (new \Facebook\FacebookRequest($this->fbSession, 'POST', $path, $params, 'v2.3'))->execute()->getGraphObject();

The code is 1363041, and the message is "Invalid upload session given".

The entire output from my script is:

```
Facebook\GraphObject Object
(
    [backingData:protected] => Array
        (
            [video_id] => 10205411650964653
            [start_offset] => 0
            [end_offset] => 1048576
            [upload_session_id] => 10205411651004654
        )

)
Array
(
    [upload_phase] => transfer
    [start_offset] => 0
    [upload_session_id] => 10205411651004654
    [video_file_chunk] => @/tmp/MyPrefix0
)
status: 1363041
message: (#1363041) Invalid upload session given.
```

I can't figure out how to fix this.  I'm giving it the session id it just gave back to me to use in the resumable upload, and it's telling me that it's invalid (I think).  Is anyone else using resumable upload, and how did you get it to work?

UPDATE: I no longer think this is related specifically to the php sdk.  I can duplicate this exact same error using command line curl and also the [API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/).

UPDATE2: Here is the most basic way to duplicate this error, using curl and your own access token and fb profile:

```
curl -X POST "https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.3/<your_fb_id>/videos" -F "access_token=<your_access_token>" -F "upload_phase=start" -F "file_size=3512954"
Response:{"video_id":"10205422595678264","start_offset":"0","end_offset":"1048576","upload_session_id":"10205422595718265"}

curl -X POST "https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.3/<your_fb_id>/videos" -F "access_token=<your_access_token>" -F "upload_phase=transfer" -F "start_offset=0" -F "upload_session_id=10205422595718265" -F "video_file_chunk=@/tmp/CHUNK0.mp4"
Response: {"error":{"message":"(#1363041) Invalid upload session given.","type":"OAuthException","code":1363041}}
```

Comment: As a side note, using `'video_file_chunk' => '@' . $fileName` did not work for me (posted content length was always way too small).  **My version of PHP is 5.6**, so I tried [CURLFile](http://php.net/curlfile) which worked much better (posted content length was correct).  This didn't fix my error message though.  Still getting Invalid upload session.

Comment: You are not alone, I'm having the exact same problem on Facebook iOS Framework.

Comment: I have a [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1434779386815592) in with facebook:   I'm waiting to hear back from them.

Comment: Facebook has now fixed this issue.  I verified that it works for me now.